# How to create a javascript object with multiple AJAX properties?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a javascript project with legacy code. There is creating an object with properties via synchronous ajax. Something like this:

```
function App() {
  this.users = $.parseJSON(
    $.ajax({
      url: '/users'
      datatype: "json"
      async: false
    }).responseText);

  this.items = $.parseJSON(
    $.ajax({
      url: '/items'
      datatype: "json"
      async: false
    }).responseText);

  this.pets = $.parseJSON(
    $.ajax({
      url: '/pets'
      datatype: "json"
      async: false
    }).responseText);
}
```

Of course, this properties are avalible in the object after initialization. But now, I need to rewrite it with async Ajax requests.
So, here is my question: is there a best practice to create an object with many Ajax properties?

P.S.: I have an idea — to use promises chain and create object after all requests. But I want to know: is there any solutions?

Comment: From the look of this code you will need to restructure more than this function to make the logic work with async correctly.

Comment: Side note: The old code was parsing the JSON twice: By specifying `dataType: "json"`, you're telling jQuery to parse it when calling its callbacks (which it will do even if there are no callbacks, as in the above). But you're also parsing it yourself from the response text. It's harmless, but pointless... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is very close. It's not so much a *chain*, the ajax calls can run in parallel, but you need to know when they've all finished. jQuery has just the thing for you: [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when):

```
function App() {
    var t = this;
    t.readyPromise = $.when(
        $.ajax({
          url: '/users',
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data) {
              t.users = data;
          }
        }),
        $.ajax({
          url: '/items',
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data) {
              t.items = data;
          }
        }),
        $.ajax({
          url: '/pets',
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data) {
              t.pets = data;
          }
        })
    );
}
```

Since `App` looks like a constructor, I'll note that the instance you get from `new App()` won't be ready to use until its `readyPromise` resolves. You might reorganize the code so that you don't have a partially-constructed object (partially-constructed objects tend to be a bad idea). We can also make use of the way `$.when` collects the results of promises for us:

```
function App(users, items, pets) {
    this.users = users;
    this.items = items;
    this.pets = pets;
}
App.get = function() {
    return $.when(
        $.ajax({
          url: '/users',
          dataType: "json"
        }),
        $.ajax({
          url: '/items',
          dataType: "json"
        }),
        $.ajax({
          url: '/pets',
          dataType: "json"
        })
    ).then(function(users, items, pets) {
        return new App(users, items, pets);
    });
};
```

Usage:

```
App.get().then(function(app) {
    // use `app` here
});
```

Live Example:

```js
function fakeAjax(opts) {
  var d = $.Deferred();
  setTimeout(function() {
    d.resolve(["some " + opts.url.substring(1)]);
  }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 500));
  return d.promise();
}
function App(users, items, pets) {
  this.users = users;
  this.items = items;
  this.pets = pets;
}
console.log("Getting...");
App.get = function() {
  return $.when(
    fakeAjax({
      url: '/users',
      dataType: "json"
    }),
    fakeAjax({
      url: '/items',
      dataType: "json"
    }),
    fakeAjax({
      url: '/pets',
      dataType: "json"
    })
  ).then(function(users, items, pets) {
    return new App(users, items, pets);
  });
};

// Usage:
App.get().then(function(app) {
  console.log(app);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: It's `dataType`, not `datatype`; I've fixed it in the above. There were also essential missing commas.

Comment: I had the same thought - but `App()` will have exited before the AJAX calls complete. Therefore if OP is expecting the `t.users`, `t.items` and `t.pets` properties to be filled immediately after calling `App()` it may cause issues

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Yup, that's what the `readyPromise` is for. I've also added what seems to me to be a better alternative (without *completely* rewriting things :-) ).

Comment: That's a really nice solution, and only minimal changes ot existing code.

Comment: Great! Brilliant solution! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Good idea ;)

```
$.when($.ajax({
  url: '/users'
  datatype: "json"
}), $.ajax({
  url: '/item'
  datatype: "json"
}),  $.ajax({
  url: '/pets'
  datatype: "json"
})).done(function(users, item, pets) {
//blabla
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You have already learned that Javascript variables are containers for data values.

This code assigns a simple value (`"Fiat"`) to a variable named `car`:

```js
var car = "Fiat";
```

Objects are variables too. But objects can contain many values.

This code assigns many values (`"Fiat"`, `"500"`, `"white"`) to a variable named `car`:

```js
var car = {type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"};
```

For more information see [Object Properties](http://www.pixelcrayons.com/javascript-development/)

Comment: @Federico: "JavaScript" (capital S) is the correct capitalization. But why bother to edit a completely irrelevant answer? :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, it was in my review queue, the previous edit looked bad and I tried to fix it. Badly, it seems.

Comment: @FedericoCulloca: Not badly in any significant way. :-) Hadn't thought about the review queue, that explains it!